# How to Programmatically Open Material UI Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm trying to test the behavior of my Material UI Select, and nothing is working. In 4.7.2, MUI changed the behavior from onClick to onMouseDown (without telling anyone) as summed up here:

https://medium.com/@nickbreid_82849/how-to-fix-material-uis-select-component-not-responding-to-click-event-22b3b0ed3019

However, in an update since then, this is not working with either.

Any thoughts?

For more context, I am trying to use Enzyme to click this Select - before, `wrapper.find('[role="button"]').simulate('click')` worked, then in 4.7.2 `wrapper.find('[role="button"]').simulate('mouseDown')` worked, and now neither works.